# An Anagram Puzzle!

Tags: anagram

Find the hidden message.

```
————————————————————————————-———-
| A | R | G | A | N | D | A | M |  
| A | W | K | C | A | E | B | R |  
| T | D | E | V | L | S | O | H |  
| S | U | J | U | O | S | Y | T |  
| A | R | G | N | O | ! | C | T |  
| S | E | W | A | E | A | R | O |  
| M | A | R | G | A | A | N | S |
————————————————————————————————-
```

Each column (separated by the lines)  represents a strip that can be  shuffled around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ANAGRAMSAREAWESO!CONGRATSYOUJUSTSOLVEDTHEBACKWARDANAGRAM

The second row was the big hint.

[Decoder](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%22%7C%20%22-N%25z%5B5%206%204%203%202%201%200%207%5DW%25%5Cf%3Dze_W%25&input=%20%20%20%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20R%20%7C%20G%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20N%20%7C%20D%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20M%20%7C%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20W%20%7C%20K%20%7C%20C%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20E%20%7C%20B%20%7C%20R%20%7C%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20T%20%7C%20D%20%7C%20E%20%7C%20V%20%7C%20L%20%7C%20S%20%7C%20O%20%7C%20H%20%7C%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20S%20%7C%20U%20%7C%20J%20%7C%20U%20%7C%20O%20%7C%20S%20%7C%20Y%20%7C%20T%20%7C%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20R%20%7C%20G%20%7C%20N%20%7C%20O%20%7C%20!%20%7C%20C%20%7C%20T%20%7C%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20S%20%7C%20E%20%7C%20W%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20E%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20R%20%7C%20O%20%7C%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20M%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20R%20%7C%20G%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20A%20%7C%20N%20%7C%20S%20%7C)